# USB type-c to DVI

Tags: 16.04, usb, adapter, dvi

Does this:
https://plugable.com/products/usbc-dvi/

Works with Ubuntu 16.04?
The web site says "Compatible with Windows, Mac, and Linux" but does not mention the versions.

Comment: I use a USB-C Thunderbolt adapter which is plug and play. The question of compatibility is at the hardware level. Is your machine compatible with it?

Comment: I use Asus ViviBook [https://www.asus.com/in/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S14-S430UA/Tech-Specs/], which has Type-C™ USB 3.1 Gen 1. The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.
Are you using it on Ubuntu or windows?

Comment: I have Dell AW17R3 which has a Thunderbolt USB Type-C port. I use an adapter which converts DPI signal to HDMI automatically (no software other than kernel regular drivers). Works in Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 and Windows 10 (also automatically). I have a different adapter from CHEMO which I ensured was compatible with Dell before purchasing. Reading user comments on Amazon helped me in selecting the $20 adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I have bought the exact same adapter and can confirm it works out of the box. No manual driver installation was needed, as they advertise: Truly Plug n Play. 
I am running Ubuntu 19.04 currently.